# What's wrong with my weight painting?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

[image]

[image]

What's wrong with my weight painting?

I can't figure why this arm is so wrong while the other as no problem.

https://pasteall.org/blend/14693cc947924462bf68488780627205

Comment: Hello, please share your file, upload and copy paste the URL it will generate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: yeh sorry i couldn't find how to do it

Comment: @moonboots Is https://blend-exchange.com/ not still the preferred upload site?

Comment: i don't know, I've been told not to use blend-exchange too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be due to the inverted normals of these faces, it made the parenting go wrong.

As you can see if you select a vertex close to the shoulder, it has been assigned to some vertex groups it should have not:

[image]

First thing, as the normals on this part are inverted, select all in *Edit* mode and recalculate the normals with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. Also select all these vertices and remove from all groups:

[image]

Now select the armature in *Object* mode, shift select the mesh, switch it to *Weight Paint* mode, select all the arm bones (shift left click) and in the *Weights* panel and *Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]

Comment: ty moonboots you really are a legend.

how do i Close this thread ?

Comment: If you mark my answer as correct (little check mark at the top left of my answer) the question will be considered as closed  ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer in order to correct a small mistake